# python metric exporter

Tags: python, metrics, prometheus-node-exporter

**SOLVED**
I’ve made a python metric exporter but is not working well, I get information from the metric.txt

**metric.txt**

```
metric_exporter prometheus-1 3 /prometheus
metric_exporter prometheus-2 10 /prometheus
metric_exporter haproxy-1 87 /etc/hosts
metric_exporter haproxy-2 85 /etc/hosts
metric_exporter haproxy-3 68 /etc/hosts
metric_exporter haproxy-4 82 /etc/hosts
metric_exporter haproxy-5 52 /etc/hosts
```

**script.py** - the script is totally made by my self, the problem that I’ve had is the script is printing me just the last line from the metric.txt and not all the lines.

```
import time
import csv
from prometheus_client.core import GaugeMetricFamily, REGISTRY, CounterMetricFamily
from prometheus_client import start_http_server
 
 
with open("metric.txt", "r", newline="") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=" ")
    for row in reader:
        print(row[1], row[2], row[3])
~                                       
    
class CustomCollector(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def collect(self):
        g = GaugeMetricFamily("disk_available", 'Disk Available', labels=['pod_name', 'env', 'namespace', 'partition_name'])
        g.add_metric(row[1], "env_prod", "namespace_prod", row[3], row[2])
        yield g


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_http_server(9800)
    REGISTRY.register(CustomCollector())
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

**the output of the python exporter should be:**

```
disk_available{env="prod",namespace="sm-prod",pod_name="prometheus-1", partition_name="/prometheus"} 3
disk_available{env="prod",namespace="sm-prod",pod_name="prometheus-2", partition_name="/prometheus"} 10
disk_available{env="prod",namespace="sm-prod",pod_name="haproxy-1", partition_name="/prometheus"} 87
disk_available{env="prod",namespace="sm-prod",pod_name="haproxy-2", partition_name="/prometheus"} 85
disk_available{env="prod",namespace="sm-prod",pod_name="haproxy-3", partition_name="/prometheus"} 68
disk_available{env="prod",namespace="sm-prod",pod_name="haproxy-4", partition_name="/prometheus"} 82
disk_available{env="prod",namespace="sm-prod",pod_name="haproxy-5", partition_name="/prometheus"} 52
```

Answer (score 0):

An indirect approach:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my_csv_filepath')
my_dict = df.to_dict()
```

You may find that you do not need the dictionary and can use the pandas dataframe for whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can not work - you are overwriting the single key your lines have in common.

Create data file:

```
with open("metric.txt","w") as t:
    t.write("""metric_exporter prometheus-1 3 /prometheus
metric_exporter prometheus-2 10 /prometheus
metric_exporter haproxy-1 87 /etc/hosts
metric_exporter haproxy-2 85 /etc/hosts
metric_exporter haproxy-3 68 /etc/hosts
metric_exporter haproxy-4 82 /etc/hosts
metric_exporter haproxy-5 52 /etc/hosts""")
```

Yours:

> ```
> data = dict()
> with open("metric.txt", "r") as file:
>     for i in file:
>         # line will ALWAYS be "metric_exporter", you use only one 
>         # key so you overwrite the values of that key over and over
>         line, *lines = i.split() 
>         data[line] = lines
>
> print(*data.items(), sep="\n")
> ```

gets you:

```
('metric_exporter', ['haproxy-5', '52', '/etc/hosts'])
```

You need to use unique keys, f.e.:

```
data.clear()
with open("metric.txt", "r") as file:
    for i in file:
        if not i.strip(): continue  # avoid handling empty lines

        # proxyname seems to be unique - use that as key
        _, proxy_name, some_number, host, *whatever = i.split()

        # the value of _ and *whatever are never used 
        data[proxy_name] =  proxy_name, some_number, host

print(data)
print(*data.items(), sep="\n")
```

to get:

```
# the dict
{'prometheus-1': ('prometheus-1', '3',  '/prometheus'), 
 'prometheus-2': ('prometheus-2', '10', '/prometheus'), 
 'haproxy-1':    ('haproxy-1',    '87', '/etc/hosts'), 
 'haproxy-2':    ('haproxy-2',    '85', '/etc/hosts'), 
 'haproxy-3':    ('haproxy-3',    '68', '/etc/hosts'), 
 'haproxy-4':    ('haproxy-4',    '82', '/etc/hosts'), 
 'haproxy-5':    ('haproxy-5',    '52', '/etc/hosts')}

# as items()
('prometheus-1', ('prometheus-1', '3', '/prometheus'))
('prometheus-2', ('prometheus-2', '10', '/prometheus'))
('haproxy-1', ('haproxy-1', '87', '/etc/hosts'))
('haproxy-2', ('haproxy-2', '85', '/etc/hosts'))
('haproxy-3', ('haproxy-3', '68', '/etc/hosts'))
('haproxy-4', ('haproxy-4', '82', '/etc/hosts'))
('haproxy-5', ('haproxy-5', '52', '/etc/hosts'))
```

You can use `data.values()` to get the tuples - the first value of each tuple is the host_name, the second value your number (as string), the third is the Uri.

Comment: thank for replying. If I want to get first column[1] should I use "data[1].items()" ?

Comment: @pe You use `data[key_name]` - this returns a tuple - you can use `name,number,uri = data["haproxy-3"]` to get the things for haproxy-3 etc. IF that is unclear, mabye use a basic python tutorial about dicts/tuples or research python iterable decomposition into variables...